# Browser get current url or response header

Tags: java, url, browser, redirect, header

How can I get the response header or the current URL of the browser( it redirects to another page) from a SWT Browser object or any other browser in java?

Comment: Have any of the answers to any of the questions you have asked helped you so far? If not you need to provide feedback, is yes then you need to start marking as correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Also see more here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/198.html)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpResponseHeaderDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.domain.com/index.html");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            Map responseMap = connection.getHeaderFields();
            for (Iterator iterator = responseMap.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String key = (String) iterator.next();
                System.out.print(key + " = ");

                List values = (List) responseMap.get(key);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                    Object o = values.get(i);
                    System.out.print(o + ", ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The url has to opened through a browser... ( ia am using java facebook )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already done something like this:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://www.foo.bar");
HttpURLConnection conn  = (HttpURLConnection) uri.getURI().toURL().openConnection();
conn.connect();         
responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
is = conn.getInputStream();
// read from IS
```

You can then do:

```
conn.getURL();
```

to get the redirected response url.

Comment: The url has to opened through a browser... ( ia am using java facebook )